# Erro ao preencher uma Matriz de Strings: A primeira linha de entrada é ignorada

Tags: c, string, uri

Eu estou tentando solucionar um problema da plataforma URI Online Judge: [Problema 1024](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1024) e estou recebendo Wrong Answer 5% (perguntei aqui, pois no próprio fórum do URI não obtive respostas).
Basicamente tenho que armazenar tantas frases quanto o usuário quiser. Percorrer cada um dos caracteres das frases e executar operações que criptografem o texto (Por exemplo, na primeira passada pela frase, é necessário deslocar os caracteres 3 posições para a direita - a letra 'a' se torna 'd' -, na segunda passada o texto deve ser invertido e na terceira os caracteres a partir da metade da string devem ser deslocados uma posição para a esquerda.

Resolvi fazer uma matriz de strings para armazenar cada uma das frases. Mas um erro ocorre na leitura: O programa simplesmente pula a primeira linha de entrada. Então, se alguém digitar '4', indicando que entrará com 4 linhas de texto, a primeira linha é pulada e o programa armazena apenas 3 frases.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar causando isso?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int n, i, j, k, cont;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    char linhas[n][1001], aux[10001];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fgets(linhas[i], 1000, stdin);

        //Deslocando três posições para a direita
        for(k = 0; k < strlen(linhas[i]); k++){
            if((linhas[i][k] >= 65 && linhas[i][k] <= 90) || (linhas[i][k] >= 97 && linhas[i][k] <= 122))
                linhas[i][k] = linhas[i][k] + 3;
        }

        //Criando uma cópia auxiliar da string
        strcpy(aux, linhas[i]);
        cont = strlen(linhas[i]) - 1;
        for(k = 0; k < strlen(linhas[i]); k++){
            linhas[i][k] = aux[cont];
            cont--;
        }
        //Deslocando uma posição para a esquerda
        for(k = strlen(linhas[i]) / 2; k < strlen(linhas[i]); k++)
            linhas[i][k] = linhas[i][k] - 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s", linhas[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A primeira entrada é um inteiro N indicando quantas frases serão lidas. Em seguida, inseridas as N frases em si.

Comment: Não sei se pode ser a causa do que você está descrevendo como "O programa simplesmente pula a primeira linha de entrada." mas a função fgets coloca como parte integrante da string lida o caractere nova linha ('\n') que finaliza a entrada. Como você inverte a string o primeiro caractere passa a ser o tal '\n' e daí ao imprimir a string ele pulará uma linha.

Comment: Entendi! Mas acho que não é isso porque o programa pula uma linha antes mesmo que eu insira algum texto. :/

Comment: O velho problema de buffer sujo e misturar scanf e fgets. Após o scanf o '\n' continua no buffer de entrada e portanto o primeiro fgets lê apenas este caractere. Consuma este caractere '\n' com, por exemplo: `scanf("%d ", &n);` (note o espaço no final do formato).

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar eu verifiquei **se** seu código possuia algum erro em C que pudesse ocasionar `Wrong Answer` no URI. Eis algumas correções possíveis:

1. Ao invés de usar:

```cpp
scanf("%d", &n);
```

na linha `7`, você pode colocar:

```cpp
scanf("%d\n", &n);
```

2. Para imprimir o resultado, na linha `31`, substitua:

```cpp
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s", linhas[i]);
```

por:

```cpp
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < strlen(linhas[i]); j++)
            printf("%c", linhas[i][j]);
        puts("");
    }
```

Pois, se você comparar o resultado do seu algoritmo com o exemplo de saída fornecido pela questão, verá que o primeiro imprime `\n` antes de cada string, algo que não acontece no exemplo, o que já ocasionaria um erro na submissão.

Veja [uDebug](https://www.udebug.com/URI/1024) para mais exemplos.

Por fim, acrescento que editei (aplicando as correções acima), rodei seu código por aqui e comparei com resultados no uDebug e encontrei diferenças novamente. O que significa que a lógica do seu código não está de acordo com o exercício.

Espero ter ajudado!